# append/insert a value/string to a list element dynamically in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
my_list = ['cat','cow','dog','rabbit']
```

but what I want is  to append/insert a character(or string) to one or more element(not all).

something like

```
my_list = ['cat','cow_%s','dog_%s','rabbit']%('gives milk','bark')
```

now updated list should look like

```
my_list = ['cat','cow_gives milk','dog_bark','rabbit']
```

one way is to do this is manually change/update the element one by one
e.g `my_list[2]=my_list[2]+"bark"`

but I don't want that because my_list is long(around 100s element ) and 40+ need to be changed dynamically.

In my case It is like

```
my_list = ['cat','cow_%s','dog_%s','rabbit']
for a in xyz:   #a is a string and xyz is a list of string 
      my_list=my_list%(a,a+'b')
      fun(my_list)
```

Comment: How do you identify which elements are the ones that need to be changed?

Comment: If they're only in order of insertion, how do you decide where *not* to insert them? Is it, e.g. `[None, "gives milk", "bark", None]`?

Comment: @GauravJain Can you make sure that the input list will have `%s` markers?

Comment: @thefourtheye : yes I'm sure!
I'll write it manually 
`lst=['a','b_%s','c','d','e_%d','f']%('bee','1')`

Comment: @GauravJain after the first pass, those `%s` are replaced by e.g. `bark`, so you can't subsequently update them. What is the bigger picture - what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @jonrsharpe question updated!

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to do, and suspect there may be a much better way around the whole problem, but I've updated my answer with something that might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
changes = {"cow":"gives milk", "dog":"bark"}

my_list = [item if item not in changes else "_".join([item, changes[item]]) 
           for item in my_list]
```

For greater efficiency if you will do this repeatedly, as JAB suggests in the comments, build a dictionary to map items to their locations (indices) in the list:

```
locations = dict((s, i) for i, s in enumerate(my_list))
```

You can then use this to find the corresponding items.

---

If you are stuck with the list of strings, some ending `"%s"`, and list of things to put in them, I guess you will have to do something like:

```
for i, s in enumerate(my_list): # work through items in list with index
    if s.endswith("%s"): # find an item to update
        my_list[i] = s % xyz.pop(0) # update with first item popped from xyz
```

Note that `xyz` will have to be a list for this, not tuple, as you can't `pop` items from a tuple.

Comment: An improvement might be to keep a second dictionary keyed with the original list items and having their indices in the list as values so the change dict wouldn't have to know what the updated values are and you would only have to iterate over the change dict rather than the list, which could result in a performance improvement if the list is iterated over multiple times. (And it wouldn't be too difficult to update the keys in the index dict if that behavior was desired instead.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a replacement string in source strings, and an iterable of replacements, then you can do something such as:

```
import re
def do_replacements(src, rep):
    reps = iter(rep)
    for item in src:
        yield re.sub('%s', lambda m: next(reps), item)

replaces = ('gives milk','bark', 'goes walkies', 'eat stuff')
my_list = ['cat','cow_%s','dog_%s_and_%s','rabbit_%s']
print list(do_replacements(my_list, replaces))
# ['cat', 'cow_gives milk', 'dog_bark_and_goes walkies', 'rabbit_eat stuff']
```

If you don't have enough replacements you'll get a `StopIteration` - you can either consider than an error, or alternatively provide a default (possibly empty) replacement to the replacement: `lambda m: next(reps, '')` for instance...

Comment: Similar to what I wanted to post, but won't work with e.g. `%d`

Comment: @tobias_k well... change `%s` to `%[sdi]` and `lambda m: str(next(reps))` - but yeah... still not quite sure if the OP's update clarifies things or not... It does just look like a replace each string (placeholder) with something else from a sequence... not sure it's meant to be as complicated as providing formatting on top... I think using `%s` is possibly misleading - it might as well be text that says "!!!REPLACE-HERE!!!"...

Answer (score 0):

Here are two more possibilities: Either, you could create a list of verbs alongside your list of animals, with `None` for animals that shall not have a verb, and merge them together...

```
animals = ['cat','cow','dog','rabbit']
verbs = [None, 'gives milk', 'barks', None]
def combine(animal, verb):
    return (animal + "_" + verb) if verb else animal
print map(combine, animals, verbs)
```

... or, if the animals already have those `%s` placeholders for verbs, iterate the animals, check if the current animal has a placeholder, and if so, replace it with the next verb. (Similar to Jon's answer, but using `%` instead of `re.sub`)

```
animals = ['cat','cow_%s','dog_%s','rabbit']
verbs = iter(['gives milk', 'barks'])
print [animal % next(verbs) if '%' in animal else animal 
                                   for animal in animals]
```